# Zurb foundation - setting the row width in sass settings not working

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation-6

I am using the zurb foundation v6. in my project, and I would like to set the width of the row to different value than it is set up by default, I have tried with setting up variable `$grid-row-width` in my `_settings.scss`:

```
$grid-row-width: 1400px;
```

But, that is not working, the row still has the width set to:

```
max-width: 75rem;
```

Comment: Try using `$grid-row-width: 1400px !important;` to check if your `$grid-row-width`value is being overwriting by the zurb foundation v6 variable, if that is the case, you can try to change the loading order to load your file the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Change the $global-width: rem-calc(1200) to something equal to or wider than you want. The default is $grid-row-width: $global-width. I think you are attempting to make it wider than the allowable global-width.

Answer (score 0):

It was the wrong order of importing files in my `app.scss` file, for some reason when I was importing `settings.scss` after including `foundation-everything` it didn't work, but after I imported `settings` file before the `foundation-everything` then the row had a width of `1400px`.

```
@import "foundation";
@import "settings";
@import "motion-ui";

@include foundation-everything;

@import "top-bar";
@import "front-page";
@import "article";
```